# My linked list implementation in Rust won't insert a new element at the end of the list

Tags: rust, linked-list, implementation, ownership

I am implementing the linked list data structure in Rust to try and learn the language. I was following a tutorial, but I noticed that their implementation inserted an element only at the start of a linked list, and not at its end. I searched for other implementations online and found they all did the same thing. So I set out to make my own version of the insert()/add() fn.

```
type NodePointer<T> = Option<Box<ListNode<T>>>;

struct ListNode<T> {
    data: T,
    next: NodePointer<T>,
}

struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: NodePointer<T>,
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Debug> LinkedList<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { head: None }
    }

    fn insert(&self, input: T) {
        let new_node = Some(Box::new(ListNode::<T> {
            data: input,
            next: None,
        }));

        let mut head = &self.head;
        loop {
            match head {
                Some(node) => {
                    println!("passing by {:?}", node.next.as_ref().unwrap().data);
                    head = &node.next;
                },
                None => {
                    head = &new_node;
                    println!("inserted {:?}", head.as_ref().unwrap().data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Somehow, whenever I call insert(), the head variable I initialize outside the loop always has the value None. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yea, you're changing the pointer, not the pointee. To change the pointee you need [mutable references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references) (`&mut ...`), not shared ones and need to dereference on assignment `*head = new_node`.

Comment: okay so I tried that, but I get an error.
`let mut head = &mut self.head;`
....
`*head = node.next;`

the error I get is:
cannot move out of `node.next` which is behind a mutable reference
move occurs because `node.next` has type `Option<Box<ListNode<T>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Comment: In the `Some` case you actually want to update the pointer (advance the pointer to the next node in the list), ie `head = &mut self.head` You don't want to change any of the nodes in the middle of the linked list after all.

Comment: *"I am implementing the linked list data structure in Rust to try and learn the language."* - note that while this is a good idea in most languages, this is not a good idea in Rust. Those types of data structures are very hard to get right in Rust, due to the strict lifetime system. Either way, if you want to continue, it is mandatory to read https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mutate your list, it is very likely that you will need `&mut self` in your `insert()` function. The fact that it compiles without is a big red flag that something is wrong.

Your mistake is the following line:

```rust
head = &new_node;
```

This line modifies the `head` variable, **not** what it points at!

What you probably intended is:

```rust
*head = new_node;
```

Now, all in a sudden, we do get the problem which I already talked about, that this isn't possible without having `self` be mutable:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `*head`, which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src\main.rs:33:21
   |
33 |                     *head = new_node;
   |                     ^^^^^ `head` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
   |
help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference
   |
25 |         let mut head = &mut self.head;
   |                         +++
```

This can easily be solved by changing all `&` references to `&mut` references.

Also, one of the `println`s had to be fixed.

Here is the final working code:

```
type NodePointer<T> = Option<Box<ListNode<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ListNode<T> {
    data: T,
    next: NodePointer<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: NodePointer<T>,
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Debug> LinkedList<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { head: None }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, input: T) {
        let new_node = Some(Box::new(ListNode::<T> {
            data: input,
            next: None,
        }));

        let mut head = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match head {
                Some(node) => {
                    println!("passing by {:?}", node.as_ref().data);
                    head = &mut node.next;
                }
                None => {
                    *head = new_node;
                    println!("inserted {:?}", head.as_ref().unwrap().data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = LinkedList::new();

    l.insert(42);
    println!("---");
    l.insert(69);
    println!("---");
    l.insert(420);
    println!("---");

    println!("{:#?}", l);
}
```

```
inserted 42
---
passing by 42
inserted 69
---
passing by 42
passing by 69
inserted 420
---
LinkedList {
    head: Some(
        ListNode {
            data: 42,
            next: Some(
                ListNode {
                    data: 69,
                    next: Some(
                        ListNode {
                            data: 420,
                            next: None,
                        },
                    ),
                },
            ),
        },
    ),
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I cannot believe I missed the fact that I was taking the argument self as immutable, while simultaneously trying to mutate the list. Thank you for the explanation and working code!